# R, parsing character into elements of vector

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am working with R and I've got a column of data frame that looks like this:

```
                                             TAGS
1                                     7:150641969
2                         7:150647969|7:150647970
3                         7:150647569|7:150648198
4 7:150645682|7:150648198|7:150650975|7:150652286
```

I need to come up with a vector from this column containing each value that in the column is separated by `|`. It would have to look like this:

```
a<-c(7:150641969,7:150647969,7:150647970, 7:150647569,7:150648198,7:150645682,7:150648198,7:150650975,7:150652286)
```

I need this in order to check how many unique values (x:xxxxxxxxxxx) appear under the column. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use `scan` like this: `scan(textConnection(as.character(dat[["TAGS"]])), what="", sep="|")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
a <- unlist(strsplit(x = df$TAGS, split = "\\|"))
a
#[1] "7:150641969" "7:150647969" "7:150647970" "7:150647569" "7:150648198" "7:150645682" "7:150648198" "7:150650975" "7:150652286"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(TAGS = c("7:150641969", "7:150647969|7:150647970", 
"7:150647569|7:150648198", "7:150645682|7:150648198|7:150650975|7:150652286"
)), .Names = "TAGS", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit` to separate the strings into individual tags,  then use `unique` to find the distincty ones.

```
TAGS = c("7:150641969", "7:150647969|7:150647970",
    "7:150647569|7:150648198",
    "7:150645682|7:150648198|7:150650975|7:150652286")

AllTags = unlist(strsplit(TAGS, "\\|"))
unique(AllTags)
[1] "7:150641969" "7:150647969" "7:150647970" "7:150647569" "7:150648198" "7:150645682" "7:150650975"
[8] "7:150652286"
```